# Scrapy MySQL pipelines

Tags: python, mysql, python-3.x, scrapy, web-crawler

I have created a scrapy project in which I have 50 crawler. I want to store the data in the MuSQL database I wrote code, but the problem I'm facing is that when ever I run the new crawler the previous data get lost. I actually want to store and save the data in the database and the old data also should retain.

This the crawler code.

```
from..items import DeccanchronicleItem
import mysql.connector
from mysql.connector import Error
from mysql.connector import errorcode
from elasticsearch import Elasticsearch, RequestsHttpConnection
from requests_aws4auth import AWS4Auth
import boto3
import spacy 
import fuzzy
from pyjarowinkler import distance
import json
import scrapy
import re

class DeccanchronicleSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'Deccanchronicle_review'
    page_number = 2
    start_urls = ['https://www.deccanchronicle.com/entertainment/movie-review?pg=1'
    ]


    def parse(self, response):
        items = {}
        i = 1
        

        movie_title = response.xpath('//*[@id="fullBody"]/div[4]/div[3]/div[1]/div[*]/div[2]/a/h3/text()').getall()
        movie_text = response.xpath('//*[@id="fullBody"]/div[4]/div[3]/div[1]/div[*]/div[2]/a/div[1]/text()').getall()
        movie_id = response.xpath('//*[@id="fullBody"]/div[4]/div[3]/div[1]/div[*]/div[2]/a/@href').getall()

        items['movie_title'] = movie_title
        items['movie_text'] = movie_text
        items['movie_id'] = movie_id


        li = items['movie_title']
        for i in range(len(li)):
            li_split =  li[i].split(" ")
            #print(movietitle)
            if 'Review:' in li_split or 'review:' in li_split:
                outputs = DeccanchronicleItem()
                outputs['page_title'] = li[i]
                outputs['review_content'] = items['movie_text'][i]
                outputs['review_link'] = 'https://www.deccanchronicle.com' + str(items['movie_id'][i])
                    
                nlp = spacy.load('/Users/divyanshu/review_bot/review_bot/NER_model') 

                def actor_mid_ner(sentence):
                    doc = nlp(sentence)
                    detected_hash = {}
                    detected = {}
                    # detected_hash = { ent.label_ : ([ent.text] if ent.label_ is None else )   for ent in doc.ents}
                    for ent in doc.ents:
                        label =  ent.label_
                        detected = detected_hash.keys()
                        # print(detected)
                        omit = ['Unwanted']
                        if label not in omit:
                            if label not in detected:
                                detected_hash[label] = [ent.text] 
                            else:
                                detected_hash[label].append(ent.text)
                        else:
                            detected_hash[label] = [ent.text]
                    return detected_hash, detected
                if outputs['page_title'] is not None:
                    sentence = outputs['page_title']
                    ner_hash, ner_keys = actor_mid_ner(sentence)
                    print('==================>' , not ner_hash) 
                    
                    try:
                        # movie_name = {}
                        movie_name = " ".join(str(x) for x in ner_hash['MOVIE'] )
                        print('-----------------------------------')
                        print(movie_name)
                        print('-----------------------------------')
                    except KeyError:
                        movie_name = '-'
                        print('NER dosenot got movie_name')
                else: 
                    print('page_title is not present')


                def elasticsearch(movie_name):
                    search_term =  movie_name
                    host = 'search-komparifyes-ushjwijscmcmdzyrbdab3hlhea.ap-southeast-1.es.amazonaws.com' # For example, my-test-domain.us-east-1.es.amazonaws.com
                    region = 'ap-southeast-1' # e.g. us-west-1

                    service = 'es'
                    credentials = boto3.Session().get_credentials()
                    awsauth = AWS4Auth(credentials.access_key, credentials.secret_key, region, service, session_token=credentials.token)

                    es = Elasticsearch(
                    hosts = [{'host': host, 'port': 443}],
                        http_auth = awsauth,
                        use_ssl = True,
                        verify_certs = True,
                        connection_class = RequestsHttpConnection
                    )

                    body = {
                            "query": {
                                    "multi_match" : {
                                            "query": search_term,
                                            "fields": ["entity_name", "aka"],
                                            "fuzziness": "AUTO"
                                                    }
                                    }
                            }

                                        
                    res = es.search(index="production-widget_id_search", body=body)
                    es_data = res['hits']['hits']
                    # print(es_data)
                    for i in es_data:
                            if (i['_source']['entity_type'] == 'movie_entity'):
                                    dist = distance.get_jaro_distance(search_term, i['_source']['entity_name'], winkler=True, scaling=0.1)
                                    if dist > 0.95:
                                        return (i['_source']['entity_id'], i['_source']['entity_name'])
                    return (None, None)
                
                es_results = elasticsearch(movie_name)
                movie_id = es_results[0]
                movie_name_es = es_results[1]
                review_url = outputs['review_link']

                outputs['id'] = movie_id
                outputs['title'] = movie_name
                outputs['title_es'] = movie_name_es
                outputs['url'] = review_url
                yield outputs
                

                
        pass

        next_page = 'https://www.deccanchronicle.com/entertainment/movie-review?pg=' + str(DeccanchronicleSpider.page_number) 
        if DeccanchronicleSpider.page_number <= 5:
           DeccanchronicleSpider.page_number += 1  
           yield response.follow(next_page, callback = self.parse)
```

and this is my piplines code

```
import mysql.connector

class ReviewBotPipeline(object):

    def __init__(self):
        self.create_connection()
        self.create_table()

    def create_connection(self):
        self.conn = mysql.connector.connect(
            host = 'localhost',
            user = 'root',
            passwd = 'Admin',
            database = 'review_url'
        )
        self.curr = self.conn.cursor()

    def create_table(self):
        self.curr.execute(""" DROP TABLE  IF EXISTS k_master_movie_reviews """)
        self.curr.execute(""" create table k_master_movie_reviews(
            id text,
            title text,
            title_es text,
            url text
            ) """)
    def process_item(self, outputs, spider):
        self.store_db(outputs)
        return outputs

    def store_db(self, outputs):
        self.curr.execute(""" INSERT INTO k_master_movie_reviews values(%s,%s,%s,%s)""",(
            outputs['id'],
            outputs['title'],
            outputs['title_es'],
            outputs['url']
        ))
        self.conn.commit()

    def close_spider(self, spider):
        self.conn.close()
```

Comment: `drop table` has a rather contributory effect to loosing data. Maybe [CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/create-table.html) would be a better SQL statement.

Comment: ```File "/Users/divyanshu/env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/mysql/connector/connection_cext.py", line 492, in cmd_query
    sqlstate=exc.sqlstate)
mysql.connector.errors.ProgrammingError: 1113 (42000): A table must have at least 1 column```
After that this error will come

Comment: Don’t just switch `DROP TABLE IF EXISTS` to `CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS`. Remove the `DROP` command, and include `IF NOT EXISTS` in the existing `CREATE TABLE` command in your code.